# Updating the values of Primary key columns in Postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, sql-update

I have the following table

```
|  ID | Seq No|
+++++++++++++++
| 1   | 12345 |
| 2   | 12345 |
| 3   | 12345 |
| 4   | 12345 |
| 5   | 12345 |
```

Both the columns are primary key values.

Here I need to increment the value by 1 for ID values greater than 2.

Following is the query I tried to execute

```
Update tblname
set id = id + 1
where id > 2 and seq_no = 12345
```

I got the following error when executing the command

> ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "tblname"
>    DETAIL:  Key (id, seq_no)=(3, 12345) already exists.

How do I solve this issue.

PS: As a workaround, I tried adding 10 to the ID value and again subtracted 9 from the ID value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the query using WITH clause and without using any workarounds.

```
with target_records as (
  select id, seq_no from tblname
  where seq_no = 12345 and id > 2
  order by id desc
)
--select * from target_records;
Update tblname
Set id = target_records.id + 1
from target_records
where tblname.id = target_records.id and tblname.seq_no = 12345;
```

Answer (score 2):

This workaround involves 2 update statements.
The first updates the ids to the negative values and the second makes them positive again:

```
Update tblname
set id = -(id + 1)
where id > 2 and seq_no = 12345;

Update tblname
set id = -id
where id < -2 and seq_no = 12345;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g7ue9xFeL9o99X3VsCpsBQ/0).
Results:

```
| id  | seq_no |
| --- | ------ |
| 1   | 12345  |
| 2   | 12345  |
| 4   | 12345  |
| 5   | 12345  |
| 6   | 12345  |
```